# What's the sudo equivalent for FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, sudo

In pretty much any GNU/Linux distribution you use `sudo` or `su`, What's the right choice for FreeBSD 10 ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

FreeBSD does support `sudo` it's likely just not installed by default. Installation instructions are here, titled: [FreeBSD: Install sudo Command To Execute A Command As The Root](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-install-sudo-command/).

As root:

*FreeBSD < 10*

```
# pkg_add -r sudo
```

*FreeBSD 10+*

```
# pkg install sudo
```

The default `sudoers` file is located here: `/usr/local/etc/sudoers`. To edit it and add rules you need to use the `visudo` command.

```
$ su -
$ visudo
```

Then to give a user access to everything as root:

```
userX ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

To become root (as userX):

```
$ sudo -s
-or-
$ sudo -i
```

Comment: Is there any way for "syntax=sh" or similar extensions? They are very useful for colorized interface.