# The "Sudo" Command are for debian-based, Linux-based distributions, right?

Tags: sudo

Let's say that I want to teach someone the command line but in the beginning, I only want to teach them the `sudo` commands. This means all the basic and useful command lines but using `sudo`.

This would require using a Debian-based operating system, correct? Like Ubuntu, for example. Or am I misconstruing certain facts?

Comment: `sudo` is not restricted to Debian, nor [even to Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116470/whats-the-sudo-equivalent-for-freebsd)... Also, start with user privileges, rather than elevated ones; introduce them to real responsibility (and pain) gently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, of course I know it wasn't Sudo wasn't restricted to Linux. You reminded me. Thanks. Can you give me an example of what you were saying? User privileges? In regards to it also explaining what the benefits of Root are?

Comment: I'm teaching beginners and I've been a Linux user for about five years. I just don't want to be the one who sounds too complicated, that's why I'm asking for such basic subjects.  I was never good at explaining but I got a position.

Comment: I don't think starting people with root privileges is the best approach. Let them learn how to use the shell and only elevate their privileges *when they need to*.

Comment: I see. Yeah, I wouldn't think so either. I didn't mean I'd start them off with root, rather teach them different user types and what they do. What they can access, etc. And wonderful idea. I will start them off with shell.

Answer (score 7):

That is certainly incorrect.
Sudo originated [around 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo#History)¹
[Debian was first announced in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian).

¹ <sub>I used `sudo` myself as early as the 80s before Linux was first released let alone Debian.</sub>